# SSIS: To run the package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Integration services or higher

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I try to launch a dtsx package from Cmd using "dtexec".

The process begins and no error encounted. But at the end I have the error message

> SSIS: To run the package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install expression task of integration services or higher

But I  checked the "Integration Services" component before installing SSDT.
So I don't understand why I have still this error.

When i launch the process from Visual studio, everything is fine.

Could you advice please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? What version of SSIS did you install? In Visual Studio is your project set to target then wrong versions such as SQL Server 2016 in project properties?

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2017. But I may have 2016 version of SSIS. 
And i see that the "Single Startup project " mentions SQL Server 2012 ... hum.

I guess the problem is this difference of version?

Comment: I would ensure the SSIS version on the server and on your laptop match. And that they match the SSIS version setting in Visual Studio. Then try again and I’m hopeful it will work.